# Setting tabular's width according to a certain number of characters

Tags: tables, width, characters, resize

I have several pages with, for each one, one box inside containing some text.

What's happening is that I resized each box according to his *\linewitdh* (but I think it\ should be a bit better actually using *\textwidth* instead).
It results from that that some boxes containing a bit of text are smaller than other containing more text.

What **I would like is to have every boxes the same size**.
But then which size ? The biggest one! (that means the size of the box having the most text).

So **what I have at the moment is the maximum number of character per line that the biggest box has**.
So I think that the point is: what should I enter in the \resizebox of each box ?

Here's an extract of some code for part of a box :

```
\clearpage
\newpage
{
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\chosenWidth}{!}{ % THE MAIN POINT SHOULD BE HERE I THINK
\begin{tabular}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em]
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
&  & &  & \\ [-0.9em]
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}
```

Here is a box bigger than what it should be:
[image]

Here is the good bigger box (the size that every box should then have) (this second picture is a bit more zoomed than the other):
[image]

Here is code to test (using XeLateX) (this code is not made to be read directly from this website but to be copy and paste then to be test):

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{pifont}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
  \font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt
 \title{}
 \usepackage{layout}
 \usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\newPart}[1]{
\part*{#1}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}


\newcommand{\newSection}[1]{
\section*{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}}

 % pour afficher dans le "toc", des lignes en pointillées entre les chapitres des livres et leur numéro de page.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

 % suppress page number in toc for parts
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\usepackage{sectsty}\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\underline}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{corrected}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
 \definecolor{error}{rgb}{0.8, 0.25, 0.33}
 \definecolor{no_change}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
 \setmainlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{greek}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{Arial}
\newcommand\Pheader{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.7pt}} % prendre la valeur de \thelongueurFinalN{\tailleDeLaPolice}
 % amélioration : ajouter un "padding" sur le tabular + agrandir le tabular et son contenu.

\usepackage{pageslts}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother
\let\oldtabular\tabular\renewcommand{\tabular}{\large\selectfont\oldtabular} %fontsize{17pt}{20.5pt}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{gospelbook}
\setcounter{gospelbook}{1}
\newcommand{\mygospelbook}[1]
{\setcounter{gospelchapter}{1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}#1}

\newcommand{\agospelbook}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}\mygospelbook{#1}}

\newcounter{gospelchapter}
\newcommand{\mygospelchapter}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thegospelchapter}\LARGE\bfseries\thegospelchapter\refstepcounter{gospelchapter}}

 % for finals N
\newcommand{\finalN}[1]{\textoverline{#1~~}}
 \newcommand{\finalNedit}[3]{\color{#3}{\textoverline{\color{#2}{#1}~~} }}  


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\foreignlanguage{greek}{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\newgeometry{margin=0.0in}
\clearpage
\newpage
 {
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
&  & &  & \\ [-0.9em]
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον φαρεϲ και τον ζαρα} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκ τηϲ θαμαρ φαρεϲ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζρωμ εζρωμ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 20 &  \\
& 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αραμ αραμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αμινα} & 5 & \textbf{4} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαβ αμιναδαβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νααϲϲων νααϲϲων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαλμων ϲαλμων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{5} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον βοοζ εκ τηϲ ραχαβ βοοζ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ωβηδ εκ τηϲ ρουθ ωβηδ} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δε εγεννηϲεν τον ειεϲϲαι ιεϲϲαι δε} & 2 & \textbf{6} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον δαυειδ τον βαϲιλεα} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαυειδ δε ο βαϲιλευϲ εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲολομωντα εκ τηϲ του ουριου ϲολο} & 1 & \textbf{7} \\
& 1 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μων δε εγεννηϲεν τον ροβοαμ} & 5 &  \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ροβοαμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αβια αβι} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{α δε εγεννηϲεν τον αϲα αϲα δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{8} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ιωϲαφατ ιωϲαφατ δε} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον ιωραμ ιωραμ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον οζειαν οζειαϲ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{9} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωαθαμ ιωαθαμ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αχαζ αχαζ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζεκιαν εζεκιαϲ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{10} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον μαναϲϲη μαναϲηϲ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αμων αμων δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ιωϲιαν ιωϲιαϲ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 4 & \textbf{11} \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}
\clearpage
\newpage
 {
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{2:11})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και πεϲοντεϲ προϲεκυνηϲαν αυτω} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και ανοιξαντεϲ τουϲ θηϲαυρουϲ αυτων} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προϲηνεγκαν αυτω δωρα χρυϲον και} & 27 &  \\
& 28 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λιβανον και ϲμυρναν και χρηματι} & 2 & \textbf{12} \\
& 2 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲθεντεϲ κατ οναρ μη ανακαμψαι προϲ} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ηρωδην δι αλληϲ οδου ανεχωρηϲαν} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειϲ την χωραν αυτων} & 16 &  \\
\textbf{13} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αναχωρηϲαντων δε αυτων ιδου αγ} & 5 & \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{γελοϲ \textoverline{κυ} φαινεται τω ιωϲηφ κατ οναρ} & 11 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λεγων εγερθειϲ παραλαβεν το παιδι} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ον και την μητερα αυτου και φευγε} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειϲ αιγυπτον και ειϲθει εκει εωϲ αν} & 29 &  \\
& 30 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειπω ϲοι μελλει γαρ ηρωδηϲ ζητειν} & 35 &  \\
& 36 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{το παιδιον του απολεϲαι αυτο} & 40 &  \\
\textbf{14} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ο δε εγερθειϲ παρελαβεν το παιδιον} & 6 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και την μητερα αυτου νυκτοϲ και} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ανεχωρηϲεν ειϲ αιγυπτον και ην ε} & 3 & \textbf{15} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κει εωϲ τηϲ τελευτηϲ ηρωδου} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ινα πληρωθη το ρηθεν υπο \textoverline{κυ} δια του} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προφητου λεγοντοϲ εξ αιγυπτου} & 19 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκαλεϲα τον υιον μου} & 23 &  \\
\textbf{16} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τοτε ηρωδηϲ ιδων οτι ενεπεχθη υ} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{πο των γαμων εθυμωθη λιαν} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και αποϲτιλαϲ ανειλε πανταϲ τουϲ} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παιδαϲ τουϲ εν βηθλεεμ και εν παϲι} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τοιϲ οριοιϲ αυτηϲ απο διετουϲ και κα} & 29 &  \\
& 29 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τωτερω κατα τον χρονον ον ηκριβω} & 34 &  \\
& 34 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν παρα των μαγων τοτε επληρω} & 2 & \textbf{17} \\
& 2 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θη το ρηθεν δια ιηρεμιου του προφητου λεγοντοϲ} & 9 &  \\
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{φωνη εν ραμα ηκουϲθη θρηνοϲ και} & 6 & \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

Or if you want a test document, I made one available here :
[tex file for testing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18GC1bqT1DYd9f2tgsa0zK26IyF_Sy6i9/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at it.

Comment: Hmm… not that easy

Comment: No problem thanks anyway

Comment: it isn't clear what you want, Normally I'd advise against using resizebox on tables at all, It produces inconsistent font sizes on each page which can be disturbing for the reader. Otherwise don't you just want `\textwidth` ?  `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` are the same in this context, so I did not understand your comment about `\linewidth`. Also you have a space character in the resizebox before and after the tabular that you should avoid.

Comment: It always helps if you provide a test document not just a fragment that can not be run

Comment: I would remove resizebox and replace `\begin{tabular}{cc|l|cc}`  by a preamble using fixed width columns so that the box is the same size on each page, using `p` columns or array package `w`

Comment: Ok I'll try to update a test document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've given a test document ;)

Comment: it is better to edit the example to be complete, not link. Your question is archived here forever and that link is likely to break.

Comment: Ok (but the code will be longer than a MWE)

Comment: Done! :) @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want to scale at all and just arrange that the table is the same width on each page by using fixed width columns or, as here, use a single multi-page table.

The font setup was inconsistent between 8-bit and unicode tex, I left some comments in the preamble,

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with current latex and should never be used with xetex/luatex
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{pifont}
% Do not use this with xetex or luatex  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
  \font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt % not normal latex syntax and doesnt fit lmodern
 \title{}
 \usepackage{layout}
 \usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\newPart}[1]{
\part*{#1}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}


\newcommand{\newSection}[1]{
\section*{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}}

 % pour afficher dans le "toc", des lignes en pointillées entre les chapitres des livres et leur numéro de page.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

 % suppress page number in toc for parts
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\usepackage{sectsty}\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\underline}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{corrected}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
 \definecolor{error}{rgb}{0.8, 0.25, 0.33}
 \definecolor{no_change}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
 \setmainlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{greek}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{Arial}
\newcommand\Pheader{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.7pt}} % prendre la valeur de \thelongueurFinalN{\tailleDeLaPolice}
 % amélioration : ajouter un "padding" sur le tabular + agrandir le tabular et son contenu.

\usepackage{pageslts}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother
\let\oldtabular\tabular\renewcommand{\tabular}{\large\selectfont\oldtabular} %fontsize{17pt}{20.5pt}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{gospelbook}
\setcounter{gospelbook}{1}
\newcommand{\mygospelbook}[1]
{\setcounter{gospelchapter}{1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}#1}

\newcommand{\agospelbook}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}\mygospelbook{#1}}

\newcounter{gospelchapter}
\newcommand{\mygospelchapter}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thegospelchapter}\LARGE\bfseries\thegospelchapter\refstepcounter{gospelchapter}}

 % for finals N
\newcommand{\finalN}[1]{\textoverline{#1~~}}
 \newcommand{\finalNedit}[3]{\color{#3}{\textoverline{\color{#2}{#1}~~} }}  


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\foreignlanguage{greek}{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\newgeometry{margin=0.0in}
\clearpage
% doesnothing after clearpage \newpage

 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

% don't scale tables but if you do, use {% \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\Large
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
&  & &  & \\ [-0.9em]
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον φαρεϲ και τον ζαρα} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκ τηϲ θαμαρ φαρεϲ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζρωμ εζρωμ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 20 &  \\
& 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αραμ αραμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αμινα} & 5 & \textbf{4} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαβ αμιναδαβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νααϲϲων νααϲϲων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαλμων ϲαλμων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{5} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον βοοζ εκ τηϲ ραχαβ βοοζ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ωβηδ εκ τηϲ ρουθ ωβηδ} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δε εγεννηϲεν τον ειεϲϲαι ιεϲϲαι δε} & 2 & \textbf{6} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον δαυειδ τον βαϲιλεα} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαυειδ δε ο βαϲιλευϲ εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲολομωντα εκ τηϲ του ουριου ϲολο} & 1 & \textbf{7} \\
& 1 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μων δε εγεννηϲεν τον ροβοαμ} & 5 &  \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ροβοαμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αβια αβι} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{α δε εγεννηϲεν τον αϲα αϲα δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{8} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ιωϲαφατ ιωϲαφατ δε} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον ιωραμ ιωραμ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον οζειαν οζειαϲ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{9} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωαθαμ ιωαθαμ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αχαζ αχαζ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζεκιαν εζεκιαϲ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{10} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον μαναϲϲη μαναϲηϲ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αμων αμων δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ιωϲιαν ιωϲιαϲ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 4 & \textbf{11} \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\newpage
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{1:11})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαν και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{επι τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ} & 13 &  \\
\textbf{12} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μετα δε την μετοικεϲιαν βαβυλωνοϲ} & 5 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαϲ εγεννηϲεν τον ϲαλαθιηλ} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲαλαθιηλ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ζορο} & 14 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βαβελ ζοροβαβελ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{13} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αβιουδ αβιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιακιμ ελιακιμ δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αζωρ αζωρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{14} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαδδωκ ϲαδδωκ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αχειν αχειν δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιουδ ελιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{15} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελεαζαρ ελεαζαρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ματθαν ματθαν δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιακωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{16} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωϲηφ τον ανδρα μαριαϲ} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εξ ηϲ εγεννηθη \textoverline{ιϲ} ο λεγομενοϲ \textoverline{χϲ}} & 15 &  \\
\textbf{17} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παϲαι ουν αι γενεαι απο αβρααμ ε} & 7 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ωϲ δαυειδ γενεαι δεκατεϲϲαρεϲ} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο δαυειδ εωϲ τηϲ μετοικε} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 19 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλω} & 24 &  \\
& 24 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νοϲ εωϲ του \textoverline{χυ} γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 29 &  \\
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε \textoverline{ιυ} η γενεϲειϲ ουτωϲ ην} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μνηϲτευθειϲηϲ γαρ τηϲ μητροϲ αυ} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του μαριαϲ τω ιωϲηφ πριν η ϲυνελ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θειν αυτουϲ ευρεθη εν γαϲτρι εχου} & 23 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲα εκ \textoverline{πνϲ} αγιου} & 26 &  \\
\textbf{19} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιωϲηφ δε ο ανηρ αυτηϲ δικαιοϲ ων} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και μη θελων αυτην παραδιγματιϲαι} & 12 &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\pagebreak
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{1:19})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εβουληθη λαθρα απολυϲαι αυτην} & 16 &  \\
\textbf{20} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ταυτα δε αυτου ενθυμηθεντοϲ ιδου} & 5 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αγγελοϲ \textoverline{κυ} εφανη κατ οναρ αυτω λεγ\finalN{ω}} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιωϲηφ υιοϲ δαυειδ μη φοβηθηϲ παρα} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λαβειν μαριαμ την γυναικα ϲου} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{το γαρ εν αυτη γεννηθεν εκ \textoverline{πνϲ} εϲτ\finalN{ι}} & 30 &  \\
& 31 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αγιου τεξεται δε υιον και καλεϲιϲ} & 5 & \textbf{21} \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{το ονομα αυτου \textoverline{ιν} αυτοϲ γαρ ϲωϲει} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον λαον αυτου απο των αμαρτιων} & 18 &  \\
& 19 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αυτων τουτο δε ολον γεγονεν} & 4 & \textbf{22} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ινα πληρωθη το ρηθεν υπο \textoverline{κυ} δια του} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προφητου λεγοντοϲ} & 14 &  \\
\textbf{23} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιδου η παρθενοϲ εν γαϲτρι εξει και} & 7 & \\
%& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τεξεται υιον και καλεϲουϲιν το ο} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νομα αυτου εμμανουηλ ο εϲτιν} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μεθερμηνευομενον μεθ ημων ο \textoverline{θϲ}} & 22 &  \\
\textbf{24} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{διεγερθειϲ δε ο ιωϲηφ απο του υπνου} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εποιηϲεν ωϲ προϲεταξεν αυτω ο} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αγγελοϲ \textoverline{κυ} και παρελαβεν την γυ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ναικα αυτου και ουκ εγινωϲκεν αυ} & 4 & \textbf{25} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{την εωϲ ου ετεκεν τον υιον αυτηϲ} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον πρωτοτοκον και εκαλεϲεν το} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ονομα αυτου \textoverline{ιν}} & 18 &  \\
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε \textoverline{ιυ} γεννηθεντοϲ εν βηθλεεμ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τηϲ ιουδαιαϲ εν ημεραιϲ ηρωδου του} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βαϲιλεωϲ ιδου μαγοι απο ανατο} & 17 &  \\
& 17 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λων παρεγενοντο ειϲ ιερουϲαλημ} & 20 &  \\
\textbf{2} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λεγοντεϲ που εϲτιν ο τεχθειϲ βα} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲιλευϲ των ιουδαιων ιδομεν γαρ} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αυτου τον αϲτερα εν τη ανατολη} & 16 &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\pagebreak
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{2:2})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 17 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και ηλθομεν προϲκυνηϲαι αυτω} & 20 &  \\
\textbf{3} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ακουϲαϲ δε ηρωδηϲ ο βαϲιλευϲ εταρα} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{χθη και παϲα ιεροϲολυμα μετ αυτου} & 11 &  \\
\textbf{4} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και ϲυναγαγων πανταϲ τουϲ αρχιερειϲ} & 5 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και γραμματιϲ του λαου επυνθανε} & 10 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{το παρ αυτων που ο \textoverline{χϲ} γενναται} & 16 &  \\
\textbf{5} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{οι δε ειπον αυτω εν βηθλεεμ τηϲ ιου} & 8 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαιαϲ ουτωϲ γαρ γεγραπται δια του} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προφητου και ϲυ βηθλεεμ τη ιου} & 5 & \textbf{6} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δα ουδαμωϲ ελαχειϲτη ει εν τοιϲ η} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{γεμοϲιν ιουδα εκ ϲου γαρ εξελευϲε} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ται ηγουμενοϲ οϲτιϲ ποιμανει τον} & 20 &  \\
& 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λαον μου τον ιϲραηλ} & 24 &  \\
\textbf{7} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τοτε ηρωδηϲ λαθρα καλεϲαϲ τουϲ μα} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{γουϲ ηκριβωϲεν παρ αυτων τον} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{χρονον του φαινομενου αϲτεροϲ} & 14 &  \\
\textbf{8} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και πεμψαϲ αυτουϲ ειϲ βηθλεεμ ειπ\finalN{ε}} & 6 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{πορευθεντεϲ ακριβωϲ εξεταϲατε} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{περι του παιδιου επαν δε ευρηται} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{απαγγειλαται μοι οπωϲ καγω ελ} & 20 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θων προϲκυνηϲω αυτω} & 22 &  \\
\textbf{9} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{οι δε ακουϲαντεϲ του βαϲιλεωϲ επο} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ρευθηϲαν και ιδου ο αϲτηρ ον ει} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δον εν τη ανατολη προηγεν αυτουϲ} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εωϲ ελθων εϲτη επανω ου ην το} & 24 &  \\
& 25 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παιδιον} & 25 &  \\
\textbf{10} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιδοντεϲ δε τον αϲτερα εχαρηϲαν χα} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ραν μεγαλην ϲφοδρα} & 8 &  \\
\textbf{11} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και ελθοντεϲ ειϲ την οικειαν ιδον το} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παιδιον μετα μαριαϲ τηϲ μητροϲ αυτου} & 13 &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\newpage
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{2:11})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και πεϲοντεϲ προϲεκυνηϲαν αυτω} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και ανοιξαντεϲ τουϲ θηϲαυρουϲ αυτων} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προϲηνεγκαν αυτω δωρα χρυϲον και} & 27 &  \\
& 28 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λιβανον και ϲμυρναν και χρηματι} & 2 & \textbf{12} \\
& 2 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲθεντεϲ κατ οναρ μη ανακαμψαι προϲ} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ηρωδην δι αλληϲ οδου ανεχωρηϲαν} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειϲ την χωραν αυτων} & 16 &  \\
\textbf{13} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αναχωρηϲαντων δε αυτων ιδου αγ} & 5 & \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{γελοϲ \textoverline{κυ} φαινεται τω ιωϲηφ κατ οναρ} & 11 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{λεγων εγερθειϲ παραλαβεν το παιδι} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ον και την μητερα αυτου και φευγε} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειϲ αιγυπτον και ειϲθει εκει εωϲ αν} & 29 &  \\
& 30 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ειπω ϲοι μελλει γαρ ηρωδηϲ ζητειν} & 35 &  \\
& 36 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{το παιδιον του απολεϲαι αυτο} & 40 &  \\
\textbf{14} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ο δε εγερθειϲ παρελαβεν το παιδιον} & 6 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και την μητερα αυτου νυκτοϲ και} & 12 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ανεχωρηϲεν ειϲ αιγυπτον και ην ε} & 3 & \textbf{15} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κει εωϲ τηϲ τελευτηϲ ηρωδου} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ινα πληρωθη το ρηθεν υπο \textoverline{κυ} δια του} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{προφητου λεγοντοϲ εξ αιγυπτου} & 19 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκαλεϲα τον υιον μου} & 23 &  \\
\textbf{16} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τοτε ηρωδηϲ ιδων οτι ενεπεχθη υ} & 6 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{πο των γαμων εθυμωθη λιαν} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και αποϲτιλαϲ ανειλε πανταϲ τουϲ} & 15 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παιδαϲ τουϲ εν βηθλεεμ και εν παϲι} & 22 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τοιϲ οριοιϲ αυτηϲ απο διετουϲ και κα} & 29 &  \\
& 29 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τωτερω κατα τον χρονον ον ηκριβω} & 34 &  \\
& 34 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν παρα των μαγων τοτε επληρω} & 2 & \textbf{17} \\
& 2 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θη το ρηθεν δια ιηρεμιου του προφητου λεγοντοϲ} & 9 &  \\
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{φωνη εν ραμα ηκουϲθη θρηνοϲ και} & 6 & \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I just retrieve the initial spacement between lines by removing "\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}" And yes I would like to be able to scale (but to scale for the whole tabular not for a single page only) for example : 0.9 <=> 90% of whole page, etc…

Comment: @gustav.b scaling tables is evil, not only inconsistent fonts but rule widths and spacing , why can you not just choose a standard font size (I chose `Large` here) ? It is anyway not possible to apply resizebox to longtable so that would be a different answer.

Comment: Ok thanks and would you have an idea about reducing the vertical alignment between lines ?

Comment: @gustav.b but the arraystretch back but with a value less than 1

Comment: Nice thanks ! it works ! But there's only one thing that I would like to resolve :  how could I make the part of the long table on a page centered on vertical? This is the last point missing: all the boxes on pages are at the top of their page

Comment: @gustav.b longtable doesn't support that, it would be possible to redefine the internal longtable output routine to allow that, but not today:-)